# Writing/Debugging Sonar plugin with hot deploy

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

General question that I cannot seem to get an answer for from the SonarQube confluence page.

I am looking to write a plugin for Sonar, but am unable to effectively setup my environment in an effective manner. I am able to connect a debugger to a Sonar server instance (by enabling the debug line in the wrapper config file) and I am able to hit breakpoints as the plugin is accessed from the Sonar UI, but....

1. I can't seem to hook up a debugger during the analysis portion of the plugin.  That is, when running sonar-runner on a project.
2. I can't seem to figure out how to hot deploy the plugin.  We should not have to build a deployable jar and move it over to sonar/plugins every time.
3. Seems I would need to ideally run Sonar out of Eclipse and emulate the sonar-runner.

If anyone has resources that talk about configuring this, that would be great.  The official website is a bit sparse.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can also remotely debug part of your Sonar plugin running on batch side if you execute *sonar-runner* with the following java options `-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000` but indeed there is no way to do hot deployment.

Comment: So this will allow me to capture the analysis portion of the plugin, then?  Very cool!

What if I were to run everything out of Eclipse - I already have the Sonar code in there. 

Without hot deploy, the iterative steps to plugin development seem painful....

Comment: yes and yes : "this will allow you to capture the analysis portion of the plugin" and "without hot deploy, the iterative steps to plugin development might be painful"

Comment: @rkd80 Unit tests should be your friends to minimize integration tests with full deployments.

Comment: Also you can try to use http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/ There were some developers, who tried, but unfortunately I don't know details.